# iTunes Connect App Validation issue

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, xcode9.3

When I upload my app to iTunes Connect using Application Loader, the new app version appears as "Processing" but then vanishes later. Then I receive email with validation errors stating:

Non-public API usage:
•    The app references non-public selectors in : didReceiveMessage:, setManagedObjectContext:

I have looked in my code and source code for the static libs  but could not find the reference to setManagedObjectContext. I am using

`[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];`

to create the context, I also have a child context initiated similarly and setting it's parentContext. I don't see any non-public API being invoked here. Am I missing anything?

About the didReceiveMessage: - its from a third party tool which I can't change. Besides these 2 areas haven't been touched since our last release in January 2018. There seemed to be no issues in the last release.

I have emailed appreview at apple with my findings. But we are in a time-crunch for releasing and this is a block which was not anticipated. I was hoping to test the app via Test Flight before submitting for review. Now that the app won't validate, I can't do that either.

What should I check to verify if our app is invoking setManagedObjectContext:?

Comment: I think your init code of NSManagedObjectContext has no problem. Because of in the tutorial of Apple, they used it. (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html).

Comment: You can use previous version of Xcode for a try, sometimes these errors occur with new Xcode.

Comment: it turns out that a third party static library that I was using had method name matching a private API. I upgraded the library and the issue went away. I used "strings" in command line to see the occurrence of the methods.